# str_extract in a vector by position

Tags: r, vector, iteration

I have a vector like this

```
cod <- c("6W41_CH", "6W41_CL" ,"6WPS_AH", "7C01_BC", "7C01_BD", "7C01_BL", "7C2L_AH", "7C2L_BI", "7C2L_CJ",
"7C8V_BA", "7C8W_BA", "7CAH_AD")
```

I'm doing an iteration and for each time I'd like to have for the cod[i] only the letter in the 6th position. I was trying to use str_extract. How I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position based extraction should be faster and more efficient with `substr`.  We can provide the `start` and `stop` positions which is 6

```
substr(cod, 6, 6)
#[1] "C" "C" "A" "B" "B" "B" "A" "B" "C" "B" "B" "A"
```

or with `str_sub`

```
library(stringr)
str_sub(cod, 6, 6)
#[1] "C" "C" "A" "B" "B" "B" "A" "B" "C" "B" "B" "A"
```

If we need to use `str_extract`, specify a regex lookaround stating that we need to extract the next character after 5 characters

```
str_extract(cod, '(?<=^.{5}).')
#[1] "C" "C" "A" "B" "B" "B" "A" "B" "C" "B" "B" "A"
```